# Trying to send an derived class through a boos::asio socket using boost::serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to send an object that is an instance of a derived class through a boost::asio socket using UDP.

Let's say the child class is PacketA with the base class being the Packet.

I'm able to serialize PacketA in the client program but whenever I try to deserialize it in the server it throws the following error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::archive::archive_exception'
> what():  unregistered class

To try and fix this I added the macros `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT` in the PacketA cpp file and the `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY` in the header file while in the Packet class I didn't add any macro, but it still doesn't work. I added these macros because of this section of the [boost docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#static_libraries).
I also tried to use the `register_type()` function to register the child classes but I wasn't successful either and the solutions seems to be worse than the macros.

Is there any obvious mistake that I'm making or am I using the API wrongly?

**Code:**

Deserialize:

```cpp
        udp::endpoint senderEndPoint;
        char buffer[MAX_PACKET_SIZE] = {"\n"};
        int bytes = socket->receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, MAX_PACKET_SIZE), senderEndPoint, 0,error);
   
        std::stringstream stringStream(buffer);
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia{stringStream};
        Packet *packet; //<-It throws the exception in this line but If I switch this pointer to 
                        //PacketA it works fine but the idea is to deserialize multiple child 
                        //packets that came from the sockets.
        ia & packet; 
        packet->bytes = 0;
        packet->senderEndPoint = senderEndPoint;
```

Packet.cpp:

```cpp
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include "Packet.hpp"
template<class Archive>
void Packet::serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned int version) {
  //I didnt add any code in here since I don't really need to serialize any information just the child packets
}

template void Packet::serialize(boost::archive::text_iarchive &arch, const unsigned int version);

template void Packet::serialize(boost::archive::text_oarchive &arch, const unsigned int version);
```

Packet.hpp:

```cpp
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/udp.hpp>

using PacketType = std::string;

class Packet {
public:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    /*Some variables and functions from packet*/

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &, unsigned int version);

};
```

PacketA.cpp:

```cpp
#include "PacketA.hpp"
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>

/*Some other functions*/

template<class Archive>
void PacketA::serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned int version) {
    ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Packet>(*this);
    ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("PacketType", packetType);
}

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(PacketA)
```

PacketA.hpp:

```cpp
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include "../Packet.hpp"

class PacketA : public Packet {
public:
    PacketType packetType = "PacketA";

    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    /*Some functions*/

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned int version);
};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(PacketA)
```

To serialize all the packets I'm using this function:

```cpp
std::stringstream foo::serializePacket(Packet *packet) { //<-Here the *packet could be any 
                                                         //packet child
    std::stringstream ss;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa{ss};
    oa & packet;
    return ss;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You registration implementation cannot see the input archive definition because PacketA.cpp fails to include:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
```

This requirement is explained in [the docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#:%7E:text=If%20no%20archive%20class%20headers%20are%20included%2C%20then%20no%20code%20will%20be%20instantiated):

> BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT in the same source module that includes any of the
> archive class headers will instantiate code required to serialize
> polymorphic pointers of the indicated type to the all those archive
> classes. If no archive class headers are included, then no code will
> be instantiated.
>
> Note that the implemenation of this functionality requires that the
> BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT macro appear after the inclusion of any archive
> class headers for which code is to be instantiated.

### Additional Notes

- The class hierarchy needs to be virtual to polymorphically (de)serialize through a pointer. Simplest way is to make sure of it is adding the `virtual` destructor.
- Note that you fail to NUL-terminate the receive buffer, which
  means you will invoke [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) unless the sent packet includes it (and it
  fits in the buffer size). So the following would be a start of what
  safer deserialization looks like:

  ```
  std::array<char, MAX_PACKET_SIZE> buffer {'\0'}; // fill with NULs
  boost::system::error_code error;
  int bytes = socket->receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, MAX_PACKET_SIZE), senderEndPoint, 0,error);

  if (!error) {
      std::stringstream stringStream(std::string(buffer.data(), bytes));
      boost::archive::text_iarchive ia{stringStream};
      Packet* packet = nullptr;
      ia & packet;
      packet->bytes = 0;
      packet->senderEndPoint = senderEndPoint;
  }
  ```

### Full Test Demo

- File `Packet.hpp`

  ```
   #include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
   #include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
   #include <boost/asio/ip/udp.hpp>
   #include <string>

   using PacketType = std::string;

   class Packet {
   public:
       virtual ~Packet() = default;
       friend class boost::serialization::access;

       /*Some variables and functions from packet*/
       int bytes = 0;
       boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint senderEndPoint;

       template<class Archive>
       void serialize(Archive & /*ar*/, unsigned version);
   };
  ```
- File `Packet.cpp`

  ```
   #include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
   #include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
   #include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
   #include "Packet.hpp"
   template <class Archive> void Packet::serialize(Archive& /*ar*/, unsigned /*version*/)
   {
       // I didnt add any code in here since I don't really need to serialize any
       // information just the child packets
   }

   template void Packet::serialize(
       boost::archive::text_iarchive& arch, const unsigned int version);

   template void Packet::serialize(
       boost::archive::text_oarchive& arch, const unsigned int version);
  ```
- File `PacketA.hpp`

  ```
   #include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
   #include "Packet.hpp"

   #define DECLARE_PACKET(Name)                                                   \
       struct Name : Packet {                                                     \
           PacketType packetType = #Name;                                         \
           /*Some functions*/                                                     \
                                                                                  \
         private:                                                                 \
           friend class boost::serialization::access;                             \
           template <class Archive>                                               \
           void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned int version);                     \
       };                                                                         \
                                                                                  \
       BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(Name)

   DECLARE_PACKET(PacketA)
   DECLARE_PACKET(PacketB)
   DECLARE_PACKET(PacketC)
   DECLARE_PACKET(PacketD)
   DECLARE_PACKET(PacketE)
  ```
- File `PacketA.cpp`

  ```
   #include "PacketA.hpp"
   #include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
   #include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
   #include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>

   #define IMPLEMENT_PACKET(Name)                                                 \
       /*Some other functions*/                                                   \
                                                                                  \
       template <class Archive>                                                   \
       void Name::serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned /*version*/)                    \
       {                                                                          \
           ar& boost::serialization::base_object<Packet>(*this);                  \
           ar& boost::serialization::make_nvp("PacketType", packetType);          \
       }                                                                          \
                                                                                  \
       BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(Name)


   IMPLEMENT_PACKET(PacketA)
   IMPLEMENT_PACKET(PacketB)
   IMPLEMENT_PACKET(PacketC)
   IMPLEMENT_PACKET(PacketD)
   IMPLEMENT_PACKET(PacketE)
  ```
- File `test.cpp`

  ```
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <iomanip>
   using boost::asio::ip::udp;

   #include "PacketA.hpp"
   #include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
   #include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
   #include <boost/core/demangle.hpp> // for test output

   static constexpr size_t MAX_PACKET_SIZE = 1024;

   std::unique_ptr<Packet> receive_packet(uint16_t port) {
       boost::asio::io_context io;
       udp::endpoint senderEndPoint;
       auto socket = std::make_unique<udp::socket>(io, udp::endpoint { {}, port });

       std::array<char, MAX_PACKET_SIZE> buffer {'\0'}; // fill with NULs
       boost::system::error_code error;
       int bytes = 0 = socket->receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, MAX_PACKET_SIZE), senderEndPoint, 0,error);

       Packet* packet = nullptr;

       if (!error) {
           {
               std::stringstream stringStream(std::string(buffer.data(), bytes));
               boost::archive::text_iarchive ia{stringStream};
               ia & packet;
           }

           packet->bytes = 0;
           packet->senderEndPoint = senderEndPoint;
       }

       return std::unique_ptr<Packet>(packet); // take ownership
   }

   struct foo {
       static std::stringstream serializePacket(Packet* packet);
   };

   std::stringstream foo::serializePacket(Packet* packet)
   { //<-Here the *packet could be any packet child
       std::stringstream ss;
       boost::archive::text_oarchive oa { ss };
       oa& packet;
       return ss;
   }

   template <typename Type>
   void send() {
       auto request = std::make_unique<Type>();
       auto msg = foo::serializePacket(request.get()).str();

       boost::asio::system_executor ex;
       udp::socket s { ex };
       s.open(udp::v4());
       s.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(msg), { {}, 9977 });
   }

   template <typename Type>
   void test_roundtrip() {
       auto fut = std::async(std::launch::async, receive_packet, 9977);

       std::this_thread::yield(); // be reasonably sure the read started
       send<Type>();

       if (auto p = fut.get()) {
           std::cout << "Deserialized a "
                     << boost::core::demangle(typeid(*p).name()) << " packet"
                     << std::endl;
       }
   }

   int main() {
       test_roundtrip<PacketA>();
       test_roundtrip<PacketB>();
       test_roundtrip<PacketC>();
       test_roundtrip<PacketD>();
       test_roundtrip<PacketE>();
   }
  ```

Prints

```
Deserialized a PacketA packet
Deserialized a PacketB packet
Deserialized a PacketC packet
Deserialized a PacketD packet
Deserialized a PacketE packet
```

Comment: Found some more problems and added a roundtrip testing demo with multiple packet types